# How to build a third list by comparing two other list with string matching.

Tags: python, list, string-matching

The answer to my question is probably somewhere around here but I couldn't find it.

I have a two lists :

```
['batman','superman','spiderman',]
['batman','ironman','superman','flash','wonderwoman']
```

I want to compare the two lists and return the matching elements as a third list :

```
['batman','superman']
```

I only found this solution:

```
list=['a cat','a dog','a yacht']
string='a cat'
if string in list:
  print 'found a cat!'
```

But it's only a comparison between a string and a list...

Comment: come on, you did not search that much. There are sooo many duplicates. one-liner: `set(list1).intersection(list2)` is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection),

```
l1 = ['batman','superman','spiderman',]
l2 = ['batman','ironman','superman','flash','wonderwoman']

print(set(l1).intersection(set(l2)))
#set(['batman', 'superman'])
```